# Using curl, grep, and sed to extract data from HTML

Tags: bash, curl, sed, grep

I am trying to learn some terminal commands, and saw this one that grabs the links of the latest Google doodle and copies it to your clipboard:

```
$ curl http://www.google.com/doodles#oodles/archive |
grep -A5 'latest-doodle on' | grep 'img src' |
sed s/.*'<img src="\/\/'/''/ | sed s/'" alt=".*'/''/ | pbcopy
```

I tried to do something similar - this command should copy the word of the day to your clipboard:

```
curl "http://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/" |
grep -A5 'main_entry_word' | sed s/.*'<strong class="main_entry_word">'/''/ |
sed s/'</\strong>.*'/''/ | pbcopy
```

I got an error that said:

```
sed: 1: "s/</\strong>.*//": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing and I've tried some tutorials on other websites but I can't figure it out. I think the main problem is that I don't understand what most of the 'sed' command does.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Of course you got that message.  You used four '/' characters.  I recommend breaking everything down into little pieces and experimenting with stuff a little at a time.  BTW, I'm guessing that if you reverse the order of the '/' and '\' you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed s/'<\/strong>.*'/''/
```

or

```
sed s@'</strong>.*'@''@
```

Comment: This fixed the error - it returns the word of the day! However, I had to change it from -A5 to -A0 and now it just returns the word! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it works just as well without the 'A0' bit

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement right, you want to extract the text between `<strong...class="...">` and `</strong>`, I would use single grep to save your `grep|grep|sed|sed...`:

also use `-s` option of curl:

```
kent$  curl -s "link"|grep -Po '<strong\s+class="main_entry_word">\K.*?(?=</strong>)'
```

output:

```
palmy
```